# Visual Studio 2019, Angular 7, Publish to IIS on Windows 10 - error looking for package.json

Tags: angular, iis

I have an Angular 7 project in Visual Studio 2019.
When I publish the project to a folder on my development PC and try to run the application in IIS, I am getting this error message:

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Pulse\ClientApp\package.json'

It's true that there is no package.json file at that location, but the runtime deployment should not require a package.json file, should it? The only file beneath ClientApp is the "dist" folder, and within that, all the javascript is bundled up in the main.xxx.js file.

Is there some kind of configuration I need to do on my PC or within IIS?

I don't understand why this is happening.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was due to an environment setting on my development PC.
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT was set to Development.
Changing it to Production made it all work.